# Value disappears after click event

Tags: javascript, onclick

I try to make a calculator with javascript with the onclick event I want the value of the button to convert an input text box.
When I write the code the value of the button briefly in the text box , but it disappears instantly.

The code that i use can you find below this text, what am i doing wrong.

HTML:

```js
    var iGetal = 0;
    function GetalRekenmachine()
    {
        iGetal = iGetal + 1;
        document.getElementById("Display").value = iGetal;
    }
```

```html
 <button id="Cijfer7" value="7" onclick="GetalRekenmachine()">7</button>
    <input type="text" id="Display"/>
```

Comment: Is a page refresh happening?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the default type of a button is submit. So either cancel the click action or set the type to be button.

```
<button id="Cijfer7" value="7" onclick="GetalRekenmachine(); return false;">7</button>
```

or

```
<button type="button" id="Cijfer7" value="7" onclick="GetalRekenmachine()">7</button>
```

Comment: epascarello is right. By default the button will be submit button. On clicking it will submit and refresh the page

Comment: Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

```js
var iGetal = 0;
    function GetalRekenmachine(event)
    {
        iGetal = iGetal + 1;
        document.getElementById("Display").value = iGetal;
        event.preventDefault()
    }
```

```html
<button id="Cijfer7" value="7" onclick="GetalRekenmachine()">7</button>
    <input type="text" id="Display"/>
```