# how to call the java scripts function from html console

Tags: javascript

I have a input box in  inside this input this below code is written,

```
data-bind="value: Report.viewModel.report().Filters()[6].Value, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"
```

when ever I pass value from console using

```
document.getElementById("filter121").value="Sample text"
```

every time I click on submit it clear the recent value and propagate with the previous one.

```
<input type="text" id="filter119" class="nmn-control min-width-100" name="filter119" control-type="0" data-bind="value: Report.viewModel.report().Filters()[6].Value, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'">
```

please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can we see more of your code?

Comment: <input type="text" id="filter119" class="nmn-control min-width-100" name="filter119" control-type="0" data-bind="value: Report.viewModel.report().Filters()[6].Value, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'">                                                           This is my full input box html code i want to automate this input box from console

Comment: how to call data-bind keydown event from console or web browser code

Comment: I don't see any `submit` in your code

Comment: I have separate submit button when after click on the button , value was removed and the , it  certainly take the previous ones that was saved before.

Comment: How can we know where the problem lies when you have a separate code and the error happens to be there. please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Anyways, put `event.preventDefault()` inside the event handler for the button.

Comment: Does this answer your question- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35988724/value-disappears-after-click-event?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Value disappears after click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35988724/value-disappears-after-click-event)